# How to use Boto3 S3 connection with proxy?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxy, boto3

I want to write the Python script to download from S3 bucket using Boto3. My code is working fine when not using proxy, but I have to run this under proxy. I have set proxy in the `Boto3.client(config=)`  and I get the following error.

Proxy set as:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                      aws_access_key_id = usrkey,
                      aws_secret_access_key = sctkey,
                      region_name = 'eu-west-2',
                      config=Config(proxies={'http': '<proxy-server>:<port>'})
                      )
```

still end up with the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

and at the end:

```
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL:"<URL>".
```

I can connect using WinSCP to AWS-S3, with proxy, that is working fine. But it pops up a warning message that I have to accept every time, by clicking ok. What is the problem here, I don't understand with Python.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `<proxy-server>` is a host name:

```
config=Config(proxies={'http': 'example.com:port'}
```

Not a URL:

```
config=Config(proxies={'http': 'http://example.com:port'}
```